# Structural Equation Modeling Reference Text

Tags: statistics, reference-request, mathematical-modeling

I'm looking for a good introductory book on the theory behind structural equation modeling in the social sciences.

I have a solid background in multivariate statistics and in pure mathematics, so the book would not necessarily have to be written at an undergraduate level.

Any good recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browsed through David Kaplan's *Structural equation modeling: foundations and extensions* and got some idea of what it was about. It's not written for mathematicians, though.

It has an interesting chart showing the kind of questions considered in SEM, such as:

> does "teacher quality" affect "teaching quality" only via "school quality"?

For what it's worth, this [review](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41303962?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) says that Kline's *Principles and Practice of SEM* is the definitive source.